# Is there a way to get around 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'DoesNotExist'

Tags: python, django

I am trying to render the same page "billing" but with different variables depending on if the user have an active subscription or not.
The problem is that I get 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'DoesNotExist' when I try to make an exception.

I have tried to use if membership is False:
return redirect without success.

```
@login_required(login_url="/login")
def billing(request):
    membership = False
    cancel_at_period_end = False
    user = request.user
    pay = payment.objects.filter(user=user).last()
    if request.method == 'POST':
       stripe.api_key = settings.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY
       #attempting cancelling  subscription
       subscription = stripe.Subscription.retrieve(pay.stripe_subscription_id)
       subscription.cancel_at_period_end = True
       pay.cancel_at_period_end = True
       cancel_at_period_end = True
       pay.paid  = False
       subscription.save()
       pay.save()
       messages.success(
            request, "Thankyou, for using our services Your membership will run to the end of your billing cycle.")
    else:
        try:
            if pay.paid:
                membership = True
            if pay.cancel_at_period_end:
                cancel_at_period_end = True
        except pay.DoesNotExist:
            membership = False
    return render(request, 'billing.html',  {'membership': membership, 'pay': pay,  'cancel_at_period_end': cancel_at_period_end})
```

```
Traceback:

File "/Users/iamsuccessful/totdapp-2/totdapp/views.py" in billing
  94.             if pay.paid:

During handling of the above exception ('NoneType' object has no attribute 'paid'), another exception occurred:

File "/Users/iamsuccessful/totdapp/totdenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "/Users/iamsuccessful/totdapp/totdenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Users/iamsuccessful/totdapp/totdenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Users/iamsuccessful/totdapp/totdenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  21.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/iamsuccessful/totdapp-2/totdapp/views.py" in billing
  98.         except pay.DoesNotExist or AttributeError:

Exception Type: AttributeError at /billing/
Exception Value: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'DoesNotExist'
```

I would expect to redirect to ('') (home page) if the user have no active subscription.

Comment: Maybe you have to change `pay.DoesNotExist` to `payment.DoesNotExist`?

Comment: `except pay.DoesNotExist or AttributeError:` Where does that come from? That's not how you catch multiple types of exceptions. You should also use the model, not the instance. Change to `except (payment.DoesNotExist, AttributeError):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access the exception from the model, e.g. `payment.DoesNotExist`.

In Python/Django you should capitalise your models, e.g. `class Payment(models.Model):`. Using lowercase `payment` makes your code hard to read, and makes errors more likely.

In your traceback you have:

```
except pay.DoesNotExist or AttributeError:
```

This is incorrect, you should use a tuple of exceptions that you want to catch, for example:

```
except (payment.DoesNotExist, AttributeError):
```

`payment.DoesNotExist or AttributeError` will simplify to `payment.DoesNotExist`, so you'll never catch an `AttributeError`.

Finally, the `DoesNotExist` exception is usually raised when you do `Payment.objects.get(...)`. Your line `pay.paid` will never raise `DoesNotExist`, but it could raise `AttributeError` when `pay` is `None`. You could simplify the code to:

```
try:
    if pay.paid:
        membership = True
    if pay.cancel_at_period_end:
        cancel_at_period_end = True
except AttributeError:
    membership = False
```

But the code might be clearer if you check whether or not `pay` is `None`.

```
if pay is not None:
    if pay.paid:
        membership = True
    if pay.cancel_at_period_end:
        cancel_at_period_end = True
else:
    membership = False
```

Answer (score 0):

`DoesNotExist` is for .get(). For filter(), I would use `.order_by` together with [0], like:

```
try:
    pay = payment.objects.filter(user=user).order_by('-id')[0]
except IndexError:
    # Handle no payment situation...
```